# WCF service is not responding

Tags: flash, wcf

A Flash program is connecting to WCF web service hosted on a server without anti-virus and without firewall and windows server 2003 64 bit environment.

The flash return Connection failed message

When I sniffer it I found that the Flash program cannot find these requests,
http://IP:2805/BLL.svc?xsd=xsd1
http://IP:2805/BLL.svc?xsd=xsd0

The strange thing is that the service work fine with asp.net.

also the same service deployed on another server, just work fine!!

Is there a work around.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked around by creating static WSDL, we copied xsd0 and xsd1 from 32 bit server, and place those files in the service root.

-follow the WSDL in the browser,

-remove all Logical resources (http://IP:2805/BLL.svc?xsd=xsd1) 
convert it to (http://IP:2805/xsd1.xml).

also fix the references between the files, and fix IPs if needed.  Reference from WSDL to WSDL0, till reach xsd0, xsd1.

Answer (score 0):

You may need a crossdomain.xml file on the server for flash to connect to a remote web service.

Comment: There is another thing we did in addition to that, check my answer